Is there a double BCH formula?
The well known Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula for two matrices $A$ and $B$ leads to
$$e^{A} B e^{-A} = B + [A,B] + \frac{1}{2!}[A,[A,B]] + \cdots$$
where $[A,B] = AB - BA$ is the $commutator$. I want to know whether there is a similar known formula for the following
$$e^{A_2} e^{A_1}  B e^{-A_1} e^{-A_2} = ?$$

You can just substitute BCH for $e^{A_1}Be^{-A_1}$ and compute.
